# RadMap for Silverlight reading in Shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, silverlight

I have created shapefiles now which is basically a couple of polygons representing rooms in a building. They appear fine in QGIS, but when I try and load it into the application (RadMap in Silverlight) the screen just goes blank.

Anybody have any experience with this?

EDIT: I'm using QGIS and have tried MapWindow too and the shapefile CRS is set to the recommended 'EPSG:4326 - WGS 84'. When I drew the polygon I made sure the scale was set to 1:1 in the hope of eliminating the possibility that the shape is just to small to see when it renders in RadMap/Silverlight.

Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: Convert your Shapefile to XAML? Silverlight XML is required to render any features - http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/dinesh/archive/2010/08/19/what-is-xaml.aspx

Comment: Hi... The silverlight control we're using (Telerik RadMap) handles this part of the process

Comment: They suggest (but not experienced in) MapWindow and setting the projection to WGS84 - http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/map/what-is-the-best-tool-to-create-shapefiles-to-radmap-control.aspx

Comment: Hi Mapperz, I've edited my question to add details about what I've tried. Thanks for the input